# mysql query performace is too low,how can i improve it

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, users,user_to_topics,topics.

```
SELECT
topics.* FROM
user_to_topics INNER JOIN topics
ON topics.id = user_to_topics.topic_id
WHERE user_to_topics.user_id=12345
ORDER BY topics.created_at DESC
LIMIT 10
```

the topics table have 5M records and the user_to_topics have 10M, this sql means find all the topics of user with id 12345 interested, order by created_at DESC

when i query like this

```
SELECT topic_id FROM user_to_topics WHERE user_id = 12345
```

then

```
SELECT * FROM topics WHERE id IN (the results above) ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10
```

it's also very slow

all the columns i used above have add single column index

how should i add index to these tables or should i change the structure of these tables？

Comment: Try to use `explain select ...` to find out where you need an index.

Comment: Try to create composite index: `CREATE INDEX user_to_topics_i1 ON user_to_topics(user_id, topic_id)`

Comment: What sql version are you using?

Comment: 5.6.21,it's still very slow when <pre>CREATE INDEX user_to_topics_i1 ON user_to_topics(user_id, topic_id)<code>

Answer (score 0):

Use EXPLAIN before your query, then see what columns should be indexed, usually those who are used more, i've reduced my AJAX request time from 1.6 minutes to 7 seconds with indexes

Answer (score 0):

use column_name instead of * in select query.

Using * gets all columns from table and might slow down your query.

use columns names that you want to need for perform query.

Comment: I can just select several columns,but i think this isn't the key of this problem, every user could have 10 thousands interested topics, no matter how i designed my sql,it use filesort to sort qualified topics,but not use index to sort them

Answer (score 0):

Try using this query below , I tjink the structure of your query might be why its taking time

```
Select * From db.topics, db.users, db.user_to_topics
where topics.id = user_to_topics.topic_id
and user_id = '12345'
order by topics DESC
limit 10;
```

This should run much more faster